# RxJava - Processing List and use result list

Tags: android, rx-java2

I have a List with Bitmaps. I want to resize the bitmaps in the background thread, and call an another method with the list.

```
Flowable.fromIterable(imageList)
        .map(new Function<Bitmap, Bitmap>() {
            @Override
            public Bitmap apply(Bitmap bitmap) throws Exception {

                Bitmap resized = ImageUtils.getInstance().getResizedBitmap(bitmap,1200);

                return resized;
            }
        })
        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
        .observeOn(Schedulers.io())
        .subscribeWith(
                //
        );
```

I want to get the result list (with all resized images) and handle errors.
Which subscriber can do it?

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The typical pattern for this is as follows:

```
Flowable.fromIterable(imageList)
    .map(new Function<Bitmap, Bitmap>() {
        @Override
        public Bitmap apply(Bitmap bitmap) throws Exception {

            Bitmap resized = ImageUtils.getInstance().getResizedBitmap(bitmap,1200);

            return resized;
        }
    })
    .toList()
    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
    .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
    .subscribeWith(
        new DisposableSubscriber<List<Bitmap>>() { 
            // ...
        }
    );
```

Comment: There is any option to retry the failed "apply" calls? Only the failed calls.

Comment: Why would the getResizedBitmap fail and how would a retry not fail it?

Comment: For example OutOfMemoryException.

Comment: How would you recover from such fatal error? Retrying with still not enough memory will keep the method crashing.

Comment: It's true in this case. Thank you